# Google maps trouble bootstrap v4

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, my google maps is not showing, sometimes i have manage to get a grey box, when im trying to have it inside a nav tab in bootstrap. I really dont have much experience with js or googles api so any input would be lovely

```
css---
    .map{
    height:900px;
    width: 300px;
}
js---
/*global google */

function initMap() {

    var westerdals = { lat: 59.9159279, lng: 10.7608717, MapHeight: 300, MapWidth: 900 };
    var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 15,

        center: westerdals
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: westerdals,
        map: map,
        title: "Fjerdingen"
    });}
html---

  <div class="col-9">

                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bilde</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#buzz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kart</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>

                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane  in active" id="profile"><img class="img-fluid" id="bildeboks"
                                                                                       src="http://placehold.it/900x300">
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="buzz"><div id="map"></div></div>

                </div>  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/AIzaSyCfvxt8VTbtTyl8lqB2hZCOSAAW22oOt8s/js?callback=map"></script>
```

Comment: `callback=map` - do you have a **function** called map? - you probably need to change the URL for the script to `callback=initMap` if your code is anything to go by - though, `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/AIzaSyCfvxt8VTbtTyl8lqB2hZCOSAAW22oOt8s/js` is complete garbage as far as googles map apis go as well - it should be something like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap`

Answer (score 0):

Firstable you have to fix some things.

- In the css you have tu use the correct selectpr, if you use a id  you have to use `#ID_SELECTOR`
- check your url for `google map`. As Jaromanda X say.

check my solution here

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
  #map{
    height:900px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bilde</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="tab-map" href="#buzz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kart</a>
    </li>

</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane  in active" id="profile">


        <img class="img-fluid" id="bildeboks"
                                                                       src="http://placehold.it/900x300">
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="buzz">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    var map;
        var westerdals = { lat: 59.9159279, lng: 10.7608717, MapHeight: 300, MapWidth: 900 };
  function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: westerdals
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: westerdals,
        map: map,
        title: "Fjerdingen"
    });

  }

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      e.target // newly activated tab
      e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
      if(e.target.id === "tab-map") {
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
          map.setCenter(westerdals);
      }
  });
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You need to trigger the resize event of the google maps when the bootstrap tab change. see the documentation of boostrap [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#tabs)

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // newly activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
  // check if the newly activated tab is the second tab
  if(e.target.id === "tab-map") {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
      map.setCenter(westerdals);
  }
});
```

That happens because the second tab is hidden when the page is loaded.